Renewcommand \sb without problems in bibliography
When I first started using LaTeX, I redefined the command \sb for square brackets.
\renewcommand{\sb}[1]{\left[ #1 \right]}
Only much later did I realise that this causes problems in the bibliography. Here's a minimal example.
main.tex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nty]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\renewcommand{\sb}[1]{\left[ #1 \right]}

\begin{document}
According to \cite{abc}:
$$
    \sb{Y = \bigcup X}
$$

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]

\end{document}

references.bib:
@article{abc,
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    doi = {123-456-78},
    author = {Author}
}

Screenshot:

In the DOI of the cited article, square brackets appear right after every hyphen.
Is it possible to redefine \sb in a way that allows me to use it for square brackets in math mode, without interfering with its function in the bibliography?

This is in general why you should not \renewcommand unless you understand what you are overwriting.  And also why you should avoid short command names.  Would it be feasible to find/replace \sb to become \squareBrackets?  Also, universal \left/\right is not a good idea.

@Teepeemm I understand that I can always use a different command, but using \sb has become a habit that's difficult to go away. I'd like to see if there are any workarounds before resorting to using a different command.

you can definitely do things to make this work, at least in any particular case, but it is the kind of thing which is going to be causing unexpected problems in places you don't anticipate and may contribute to mysterious problems which take you a long time to track down. that is, in the end, either breaking the habit or configuring your editor to automatically replace \sb with \squareBrackets is probably the best solution. it's probably unlikely you'll ever need to type \sb directly, so configuring your editor might be the best option: you keep the shortcut and avoid the fallout.

Could you live with \SB instead of \sb?

A colleague of mine used to define \c as a shorthand for \gamma. It “worked fine”, until he had a coauthor named Şahin. Can you spot the problem? Well, it’s similar to yours. Don’t redefine commands, unless you precisely know what the implications are; in particular, \sb is used in many other packages or user code.

TL;DR;
Don't redefine \sb. Use a different name.
Extended answer
When I teach about \newcommand and \renewcommand, I always warn the students about using the latter without precisely knowing what they're doing. I show them effects of redefining \box or \fi, but also tell them about the colleague who used \c as a shorthand for \gamma (together with \a for \alpha and \b for \beta). Everything seemed to “work fine”, until his coauthor was named Şahin and LaTeX started to deliver weird error messages.
DON'T redefine \sb: it's an important command which is used by several packages. For instance
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\renewcommand{\sb}[1]{\left[ #1 \right]}

\begin{document}

$\prescript{a}{b}{C}$

\end{document}

would produce

which hardly qualifies for something less than “amazing”.
On the other hand, something like
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\SB}[1]{\left[ #1 \right]}

\begin{document}

\[
\SB{\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i}
\]

\end{document}

(note the absence of $$ that should never be used in a LaTeX document) would produce

which is simply ugly and wrong. Compare with
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\biggl[\,\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\biggr]
\]

\end{document}


I mean, macros can be handy, but doing things “automatically” conflicts with “good typesetting”.
